# Address of variable lower than address of a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
int main(int argc  , char *argv[] ) 
{
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8] , buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one,"one");
    strcpy(buffer_two,"two");
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and containt \'%s\' \n ",buffer_two,buffer_two);

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and containt \'%s\' \n ",buffer_one,buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n",&value,value,value);
}
```

I got this result:

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ffd75d46720 and containt 'two' 
 [BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ffd75d46710 and containt 'one' 
 [BEFORE] value is at 0x7ffd75d4670c and is 5 (0x00000005)
```

As you can see the address of buffer_two is higher then buffer_one (because it's pushed on the heap and and the heap goes up to higher addresses) here everything is okey.

What I don't understand why the address of the Value variable is smaller than both , I think it must be higher because variables are stored on the stack! and the stack has higher addresses than the heap!

Comment: Why do you think `buffer_one` and `buffer_two` would be on the heap, rather than the stack? They are all local/automatic variables after all.

Comment: `value`, `buffer_one` and `buffer_two` are all on the stack. `value` is at the lowest address then we have `buffer_one` and at the higest address we have `buffer_two`. Where is the problem ? BTW: the compiler is free to arrange the variables on the stack in any order.

Comment: `the stack has higher adresses than the heap` - what makes you think that? You may have observed this once somewhere, but the standard doesn't say anything at all about it, they are free to be located anywhere in the address space. Also, nitpick, but it's `address` and `contains`, not `addresse` and `containt`.

Answer (score 0):

Because all three variables are defined within a function, they all live on the stack.  The stack typically grows downward, so it looks like space for `buffer_two` was pushed onto the stack first, followed by 8 padding bytes, followed by `buffer_one`, followed by `value`.

That being said, how variables are placed on the stack is implementation defined, and could vary in the same implementation when seemingly unrelated code changes are made.

For example, on my system this code outputs the following:

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0xbfb16110 and containt 'two' 
 [BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0xbfb16118 and containt 'one' 
 [BEFORE] value is at 0xbfb16120 and is 5 (0x00000005)
```

In this case, the variables were placed on the stack in the opposite order, and without the 8 byte padding.

Comment: "how variables are placed on the stack" is NOT implementation-defined.  The C standard does not mention a stack at all, it only requires that local variables work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for the compiler to store separate objects in any particular order (whether that storage comes from the stack, heap, or some other section of memory).  It does not have to lay them out in the order in which you declared them, nor do they have to be adjacent in memory.

`struct` members must be laid out in the order in which they are declared, but they may or may not be adjacent; there may be "padding" bytes between members, again due to alignment requirements.